# Debugger not stopping at breakpoint for PHP in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: php, asp.net, debugging, iis, visual-studio-2013

I am using Local IIS Express Web Server.
**Invalid information were received from PHP.Debugger.Server.** 
Getting this warning and the debugger not stopping at breakpoint in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: How are you debugging php in visual studio ? are you using any extension in Visual Studio  like PHP Tools for Visual Studio ?

Comment: I did install PhpTools.1.16.7912.msi PHP tool. I can see the details of PHP xdebug in Visual Studio -> Options -> PHP Tools -> Interpreter

Comment: This is a third party Visual studio extension and this issue does not seem to be related to VS or asp.net or IIS. You should probably ask here http://support.devsense.com/